# Why the Hodge filtrations vary holomorphically.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Suppose we have a fibration over the unit disc $\Delta$ of $\mathbb{C}$,
\begin{equation}
\pi: X \rightarrow \Delta
\end{equation}
such that all the fibers are smooth projective manifolds. The for every $\varphi \in \Delta$, we have a Hodge decomposition
\begin{equation}
H^n(X_{\varphi}, \mathbb{C})=\oplus_{p+q=n}H^{p,q}(X_{\varphi})
\end{equation}
which determines a filtration
\begin{equation}
F^p_{\varphi}:=\oplus_{k \geq p}H^{k,n-k}(X_{\varphi})
\end{equation}

**Question**: lots of references claim that $H^{p,q}(X_{\varphi})$ varies smoothly with respect to $\varphi$, i.e. $\cup_{\varphi}H^{p,q}(X_{\varphi})$ only forms a smooth bundle over $\Delta$. But $F^p_{\varphi}$ varies holomorphically with respect to $\varphi$, i.e. $\cup_{\varphi} F^p_{\varphi}$ forms a holomorphic bundle over $\Delta$. Could anyone explain why? Any examples?